# PostgreSQL database synchronization

Tags: postgresql

My company has two locations: Head Quarters (HQ) and a sub location (SL).

Both locations (HQ and SL) has separate PostgreSQL databases with the same schema and they will do transactions (insert/delete/update) in off-line. When both comes on line, both databases need to be synchronized (ie, come in the same state). Is it possible?

Comment: It’s probably possible. Have you looked into logical replication?

Comment: Please tag for the version of Postgres you are using.

Comment: Are they generally online except for brief interruptions?  Or generally offline?

Comment: Generally  Online,but   interrupts are  very common

Comment: postgres version is 9.6